# How to mock generic method without specifying type parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have an interface

```
public interface ISomething
{
    ISomethingElse<T> GetInstance<T>();
}
```

Now I want to mock this

This works:

```
var mock = new Mock<ISomething>();
mock.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<MyClass>()).Returns(Mock.Of<ISomethingElse<MyClass>>());
```

But I need a generic approach

If the return Type would just bei `ISomethingElse` I could write

```
var mock = new Mock<ISomething>();
mock.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<It.IsAnyTpye>()).Returns(Mock.Of<ISomethingElse>());
```

But (obviously) this doesn't work.

How can I achive this in a more generic way?

```
var mock = new Mock<ISomething>();
mock.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<It.IsAnyTpye>()).Returns(Mock.Of<ISomethingElse<???>>());
```

Comment: This is not possible I think.  Also, when unit testing, we test with a definite set of criteria and verify the definite result, so does the intended generic test makes sense? What are we testing?

Comment: @Jimmy I don't want to test `GetInstance` but I get a `NullReferenceException` on the method I want to test. See my answer which is not what I asked for but a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a good workaround.

In my case I want to test a method from `MyClass` that uses `ISomething`.
`ISomething` itself is tested elsewhere.

```
public void MyMethod(ISomething something)
{
    something.GetInstance(this).Setup();
    // I want to test the following code
}
```

I just don't want `something.GetInstance(this).Setup();` to throw a NullReferenceException.

I solved it with `DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock` which does exactly what I want to achive.

```
new Mock<ISomething>() { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
```